Cast string in objectId type field in mongodb
I have a problem in implementing a logic, please provide some ways to solve this problem.
i have a schema named sales and a schema named development. In Sales schema there is a field for development:
development: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Development" },
i am also populating this development field when getting all sales.
But now the client is asking that he can also add "other"(as a string) in order to differentiate that the sales is from other development which is not on our site.
So i am unable to make logic because i want to also populate developments when i will find all sales or any sale details.
please suggest me some way to implement this logic.

Modify the Schema: You can modify the development field in the Sales schema to allow either a reference to a Development document or a string indicating "other". Here's how you can modify the schema:

Handle Population Logic: When querying sales data, you can check if the development field is an ObjectId or a String. If it's an ObjectId, you can populate the Development document as usual. If it's a String indicating "other", you can handle it differently. Here's an example of how you can handle the population logic:

Can you tell me how to check before populating fields that this field is an ObjectId or a string?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you please share the schema of Development. What is the real purpose of this collection? You can set reference to more than one collections. Dynamic References via refPath and Dynamic References via ref - are the two different ways to do it. For more please see the documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, and revert for any further assistance.

You can use mongo aggregation pipeline, use addField to add the field if development is not other, and on that field, use lookup from the development collection.
This will get all the documents with 'others' as well as 'development_id', and the one with 'development_id' will have details from development collection.
